# How to add event handler to dynamically fetched data from mongoose

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am fetching data from db and displaying on screen like below

[image]

when user clicks on book appointment button he should able to see the slots which have a div with id #slot-display

but it works only on first book appointment button. if we click second book appointment button that is for name  Dr manav it toggles the same first book appointment button and show div for slots for dr smira. here div means the slot timings i am showing like 9.31 15.32 etc

[image]

here is what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click", "#slot_toggle", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#slot-display").toggle();

  });
});
```

```
#slot_toggle - button id
#slot-display - div to toggle
```

ejs code

```
<div class="doc-wrapper-parent">
        <% list.forEach(item=>{%>
        <form action="/doctors/<%=item._id%>" id="formid" method="GET">
          <div class="doc-wrapper">
            <div class="doc-list py-2" id="parent">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">
                    <span
                      ><h2>
                        <%=item.createdBy.name %>
                      </h2></span
                    >
                  </h5>
                  <div class="info-grid">
                    <div class="left-info">
                      <p class="card-text py-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-medal"></i
                        ><span><%= item.speciality%></span>
                      </p>
                      <p class="card-text py-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-certificate"> </i
                        ><span><%= item.education%></span>
                      </p>
                      <!-- <p class="card-text py-1"></span>
                </p> -->
                      <p class="card-text py-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-clock"></i
                        ><span>
                          <%= item.experience %> Years of experience</span
                        >
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-info">
                      <p class="card-text py-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i
                        ><span> <%= item.location %> </span>
                      </p>
                      <span class="info"
                        ><p class="card-text py-1">
                          <i class="fas fa-hospital"></i
                          ><span><%= item.hospitalList %></span>
                        </p></span
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="button-div">
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-dark my-3 toggleBtn"
                      type="submit"
                      id="slot_toggle"
                    >
                      Book Appointment
                    </button>
                  </div>

                  <div class="slot-parent" id="slot-display">
                    <div class="slot_child_divs">
                      <%if(item.slots){%> <% for(i in slots) {%> <%=
                      slots[i].startTime %> <%}%> <%}%>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <% })%>
```

Comment: you have duplicated IDs

Comment: duplicated ids?

Comment: in the loop **<% list.forEach(item=>{%>** you declare always **<div class="slot-parent" id="slot-display">** !!!   For this reason ......but it works only on first book appointment button

Comment: but if we take this div out of the loop it goes directly to bottom....